# django-http-proxy prepending slash

Tags: django, http-proxy

I have this in my `urls.py`

```
from httpproxy.views import HttpProxy

urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    url(r'^proxy/(?P<url>.*)$', HttpProxy.as_view(base_url=settings.PROXY_URL))
)
```

And my `settings.py`

```
...

PROXY_URL = 'http://external.com'

...
```

My problem is when accessing the URL `http://localhost:8000/proxy/`, I can see from the log of `http://external.com` it is returning `404` because the url has an extra slash prepended so for example:

`http://localhost:8000/proxy/test/` will log `"GET //test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 15447`

I have been digging but couldn't find the bone! If all the masters would be kind enough to lend a bone for this hunger?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one answered (I even got a badge because no one answered, how cool is that?), I will post my solution, which was solved 2 days after the question was asked.

1 - Because of [this issue pointed out by a friend](https://github.com/yvandermeer/django-http-proxy/issues/11), I have steered away from using `django-http-proxy`.

2 - So I resorted to a better library which proxies all HTTP Methods, unlike `django-http-proxy` that can only proxy `GET`. Meet [`django-revproxy`](https://github.com/TracyWebTech/django-revproxy).

3 - Which introduces another problem — The Cookie Conflict. This happens because I have two django instances. The solution is to explicitly declare the cookie path in one of your django app so it won't be using the same path. Just add in `settings.py` these two lines:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "yourApp_session_id"
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME =  "yourApp_csrftoken"
```

4 - That's it. I hope this solution will help those on the lookout.